# Reveal parts of multiple \item at the same time

Tags: beamer, itemize, pause

In the following MWE, I'd like the frame to consist of two slides. On the first slide, only the 3 items (Item 1, Item 2, Item 3) should be visible. On the second slide, additionally, the 3 explanations (explanation 1, explanation 2, explanation 3) should be visible, too.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \makebox[4cm][l]{Item 1}explanation 1
        \item \makebox[4cm][l]{Item 2}explanation 2
        \item \makebox[4cm][l]{Item 3}explanation 3
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I read about `item<X>` to specify that an item should appear only on slide X, but that affects the whole item -- is it possible to achieve this behaviour for parts of items, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use beamer overlays, like `\only`, `\visible` etc., to delay specific parts of the text.

Please also note, that you don't need to load `graphicx`, beamer already loads this for you.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \makebox[4cm][l]{Item 1}\visible<2->{explanation 1}
        \item \makebox[4cm][l]{Item 2}\visible<2->{explanation 2}
        \item \makebox[4cm][l]{Item 3}\visible<2->{explanation 3}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]